# SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT is set to false explicitly by Azure Cli

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-function-app, azure-cli2

I am using Azure Cli in Jenkins build to deploy my `nodejs` azure functions to azure. I need Kudu to build the npm packages to reduce the deployment time on Jenkins side.

I have `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true` in Azure Functions configurations but Azure Cli explicitly set it to false while deploying the artifacts! So the application will be left out without `node_modules` folder.

I am using command similar to the following:

`az functionapp deployment source config-zip --src artifacts.zip --resource-group MyGroup --subscription MySubscription --name MyFunction --slot pre`

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a similar issue with a version regression in the past. Check out the issue around this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11246

You can install `Azure CLI 2.0.77` or `2.0.75` using `pip` and see if this issue is vanished:

```
pip install azure-cli==2.0.75
```

May be, this is an issue with a latest update.

Comment: I am using the latest Azure Cli docker container (v 2.13.0). Is not supposed to be fixed there?

Comment: Can you try rolling back to these versions once? So that it can be confirmed if it's an update or something else.

Comment: Pipe caused some errors but I used `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.0.77` and result was the same. There are 2 warning messages `Setting ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD to false` and `Setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to false`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `$env:SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in my script solved this problem

Comment: could you please explain the syntax you have used above? 
I am trying to understand how and where you set the value SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

Comment: Those are PowerShell script used to set environment variable, I think he sets the env var before running Azure CLI

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue when using the `az functionapp deployment source config-zip` command. When this command is executed, the value of `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` set to `true` in the function app's application settings will be overridden and changed to `false`.

To prevent that, set the `--build-remote` flag to `true`.
E.g. `az functionapp deployment source config-zip --src artifacts.zip --resource-group MyGroup --subscription MySubscription --name MyFunction --slot pre --build-remote true`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_deployment_source_config_zip

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently also the option to include a `.deployment` file with the config in it.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization

and: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments